# How do I make a counting system in PHP that resets?

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm working on a school project. It involves PHP and Python.
What I should make is like this:
Theres a button, when I press once, should do this code, second should to that code, third, etc... then after X clicks it should reset to first click. (This is on a raspberry pi, code will put led at 25%/50%/75%/100%/0% trhu python.)

This is the PHP code I got so far. (Don't fortget the html to add a simple button.)

```
$_SESSION["aantal"] = isset($_SESSION["aantal"]) ? $_SESSION["aantal"]: 0;

if($_POST[ALLES_IN_EEN]){ 
$_SESSION["aantal"]++;
    if($_SESSION["aantal"] == 1){ 
        $a- exec("sudo pkill python"); 
        echo $a;
        $a- exec("sudo python /var/www/4/0procent.py"); 
        echo $a; 
        }

    if($_SESSION["aantal"] == 2){ 
        $a- exec("sudo pkill python"); 
        echo $a; 
        $a- exec("sudo python /var/www/4/25procent.py"); 
        echo $a; 
        } 

    if($_SESSION["aantal"] == 3){ 
        $a- exec("sudo pkill python"); 
        echo $a; 
        $a- exec("sudo python /var/www/4/50procent.py"); 
        echo $a; 
        } 

    if($_SESSION["aantal"] == 4){ 
        $a- exec("sudo pkill python"); 
        echo $a; 
        $a- exec("sudo python /var/www/4/75procent.py"); 
        echo $a; 
        } 

    if($_SESSION["aantal"] == 5){ 
        $a- exec("sudo pkill python"); 
        echo $a; 
        $a- exec("sudo python /var/www/4/100procent.py"); 
        echo $a; 
        $_SESSION["aantal"]=0;
        }
}
```

But somehow its not working. I've never done PHP before so I was wondering what I'm doing wrong. I'm used to C# so I used that way of thinking but its not working here :)

Regards

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: When I click the button, the first if statement works. Led goes to 0% (with python script). But when I click it a 2nd time, it doesnt go to 25%, third time doesnt go to 50%, etc.... It probably also wont set aantal = 0 when aantal == 5, I've never used PHP so I hope I'm doing it right :P

Answer (score 0):

The PHP script is restarted every time you call it. So `$aantal``is always 1 (being 0 and then ++) and never more. You have to store it somewhere persitent, for example in [$_SESSION](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session).
It should work when you add in the end

```php
$_SESSION["aantal"]=$aantal;
```

and begin the script with

```
session_start();
$aantal = isset($_SESSION["aantal"]) ? $_SESSION["aantal"] : 0;
```

instead of `$aantal = 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you run your .php file, it's set `$aantal = 0;`. So it will never reach `if($aantal == 2){`

As a solution, you need to persist the "how many runs am I" information somewhere.
If you are running a HTTP server, you will have a session variable, differentiated by each client using cookies.

So, put at the top of your file:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["aantal"] = isset($_SESSION["aantal"]) ? $_SESSION["aantal"]: 0;
```

and everywhere you use `$aantal` replace with `$_SESSION["aantal"]`.

As a second approach, if you are using php_cli, without webserver, you will need to store in some database or even a textfile. In this case, create a file named `aantal.txt` with `0` inside it put this at the top of your file:

```
$file = 'aantal.txt'
$aantal = file_get_contents($file);
```

and at the bottom of you file, you need to update your text file "database" to write the current `$aantal` number:

```
file_put_contents($file, $aantal);
```

Comment: I tried the first way; so I got this now: https://gyazo.com/607216415b2e0877c00734332e87ab82
site just wont load now :P Keeps on loading

Comment: Check the first line `$aantal = isset ...` you are not using `$aantal` anymore, use only the session var.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/3ebd42ff9ef1bec7c5f8b3bfc3d2457f
Like this? :) Sorry for the noob question man, first time using PHP and its pritty complicated atm for me :)

Comment: Site keeps loading.... It must be in this part of the code because when I hide/remove it site just loads fine.

Comment: `$a- ` I guess should be `$a = `.. Anyway, add `//` comment to the lines where python code is executed. If it's moving through different `$aantal` levels, seems your problem is solved, and you need to find out about the python issue.

Comment: I have the same question, like 0%/25%/50%/75%/100% buttons but appart buttons, not all in 1 button with a cycle thru system, if you see what I mean. there the $a- is used and also the python scripts work, its just something in here thats not working out. If youd wish to see my python code I can put it in here as well

Comment: https://gyazo.com/3a623ea8ad5f4d5edeaf4aeab5c3404e
Sorry for the dutch language, AAN = on, UIT = off and then you have the percantages buttons. Im looking for a way to get all the percentage buttons to get it to work in 1 button (last one)

Comment: Also I //'d the python code, how do I check if its moving through aantal levels?

Comment: Weird? Now I didnt change anything, site loads now. this is my code atm:
https://gyazo.com/50f8c0a611ceceec377e72f028c54f09
but bad luck, its still not putting my led at the scripts in python like it should :/ any ideas?